# json based validation issue in redux form

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form, redux-thunk

issue in performing validation based on json in redux form below is the

```
**json creating dynamic form**

const simplefield = [
  {
    name: "firstname",
    type: "text",
    placeholder: "Enter Name",
    isrequired: "true",
    maxLength: "5",
    minLength: "3",
    checkrules: {
      requiredfield: { message: "required firstname" },
      maxlength: { value: 5, message: "maxlength" },
      minlength: { value: 3, message: "minlength" }
    }
  },
  { name: "age", type: "number", placeholder: "Enter age" },
  {
    name: "email",
    type: "email",
    placeholder: "Enter Email",
    checkrules: {
      requiredfield: { message: "required" },
    },
    defaultValue: "email@email.com"
  },
]
```

**validation code**

```
const validate = (values, props) => {

const validation = props.fields.filter(field => field.checkrules);
const error = {};
 validation.map((v, i) => {
  if ("requiredfield" in v.checkrules) {
   if (values[v.name] === undefined || values[v.name] === "") {
    return (error[v.name] = v.checkrules.requiredfield.message);
   } else if (!/\S+@\S+\.\S+/.test(values.email)) {
    return (error.email = "invalid");
   }
 }
 });
}
```

here i am creating a redux form based on json which renders field(which i was able to implement it) but i am stuck in performing dynamic validation based on field named **checkrules** in below json,below is code of implementing validation which is not correctly implemented,please provide me solution

Answer (score 0):

```
export const createModalValidation = value => {
    const errors = {};

    if (!value.rules || !value.rules.length) {
      errors.rules = { _error: 'At least one member must be entered' };
    } else {
      const rulesArrayErrors = [];
      value.rules.forEach((member, memberIndex) => {
        const ruleErrors = {};
        if (!member || !(member.name == 'your_key')) {
          here can check any number of condition...

          ruleErrors.fact = 'Required';
          rulesArrayErrors[memberIndex] = ruleErrors;
        }
       });
      if (rulesArrayErrors.length) {
        errors.rules = rulesArrayErrors;
      }
    }
    return errors;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer,can you let me know what should i pass in value parameter

Comment: value is what what i got after submitting form [check here](https://redux-form.com/7.2.0/docs/gettingstarted.md/)

Comment: yes true,but how should i know that this particular field is having validation as required,minlength and so,and i showed you json with checkrules object, and there are validation rules inside it

Comment: yes that you can give with value.key > maxLength or vice versa for minLength through error message.